# Query 4.5 million record postgresql database quickly

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a SQL Server database with 4.5 million records. I reproduced the same database with the exact same 4.5 million records in a PostgreSQL database.

When querying the SQL Server database, I am using FTS which returns data sub 1 second which is great. **The problem is**, when using the Postgresql without FTS, it is obviously extremely slow (25 - 45 seconds if not longer). I am struggling to find out what is the best PostgreSQL FTS equivalent?

API is .net core c# using Entity framework core.

Data is a list of companies. So a typical search might 'Kelly Construction' and I'd expect the API / DB to return results where company name column contains or is 'like' 'kelly construction'.

Comment: Postgres [supports FTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) as well. But a seq scan on a table with only 5 million rows shouldn't take 45 seconds on modern hardware.

Comment: Postgres has GIN and GIST indexes (and trigram) which are useful for various types of string searches.

Comment: I closed this and provided links to 2 similar questions. If the answers there are not helpful enough for your issue, please make a comment here and we could reopen.